# exponentiate log2(outcome) in rms package

Tags: r, rms

I have a highly skewed outcome variable TnI, which I have transformed using log2. I have used the excellent rms package to plot the OLS predictions. Is it possible to exponentiate log2(TnI) to get the plots of predictors vs TnI instead of log2(TnI)? Many thanks, Annemarie

```
dd <- datadist(df); options(datadist="dd")
m1 <- ols(log2(tni) ~ age + ischaemia, data=df, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
plot(Predict(m1)
```

Comment: As an aside, if the skewness is due to restrictions on the data (eg. `tni` is a strictly positive continuous variable, like a size or a concentration) then consider fitting the model as a GLM (generalised linear model). The model you are using is for the expectation of log2(y) not the expectation of y itself - the GLM instead will model the expectation of y.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Using GLM, would I not need to specify the family  eg = gaussian, which would need tni to be normally distributed?

Comment: No; if `tni` is physically constrained to be positive (can't have a zero weight animal for example) then this implies mean-variance relationship and that the response conditional upon the covariates has some distribution, say Gamma. Such data will be skewed. Hence, if the skew you observe in `tni` is the result of a lower bound at 0 (and thence 0 variance at a value of 0), instead of fitting a linear model to the log of Y, I would fit a GLM with `family = Gamma(link = "log")` for example.

Comment: @GavinSimpson fantastic, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes; the inverse of the transformation `xx = log_2(x)` is `x = 2^xx`. More generally, the inverse of taking logs of `x` using base `b` is `b^x`.

For example:

```
> x <- c(4,8)
> xx <- log2(x)
> 2^xx
[1] 4 8
```

For the `Predict()` function/method, you'll need to do

```
predvals <- 2^Predict(m1)$yhat
```

or something similar, to extract the predicted values from the data frame returned by `Predict()`. If there are components `lower` and `upper` (if you requested a confidence interval) then you can extract and back transform these in the same manner.

Comment: Great thank you for your help. How would you then plot these predicted values to visualise the relationships between tni and age, ischaemia?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Frank's **rms** package, but if `plot(Predict(m1))` does what you want, I would try `pred <- Predict(m1)` followed by `pred <- transform(pred, yhat = 2^yhat, lower = 2^lower, upper = 2^upper)`. Finally `plot(pred)`, but I'm assuming that `plot(Predict(m1))` already does what you want just without the back transformation

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't quite work for me, but I can see that it could do... Yes, plot(Predict(m1)) does exactly what I would like, with individual plots for log2(tni) vs age and log2(tni) vs ischaemia. I would just like to get rid of the log2 for ease of clinical interpretation.

Comment: If you can put up a reproducible example I will look in more detail.